# Prototype "Bind" method issue

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift();
    return function(){
        return fn.apply(object,
            **args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))**);
    };
};
```

This function is in Prototype. Does it equal to:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift();
    return function(){
        return fn.apply(object,**args**);
    };
};
```

In my opinion, `args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) == args`, since the anonymous
function haven't any arguments. What is the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they aren't the same.

Tthe purpose of concatenating the arguments is to provide a way of [*partially apply*](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) (or [*curry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)) the function, pre-filling arguments when `bind` is used and being able to add more later when the function that `bind` returns is used, for example:

```
var obj = {
  fx: function() {
    alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ', '));
  }
};

var fx2 = obj.fx.bind(obj, 1, 2, 3);
fx2(4, 5); // Alerts "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

As you can see in the last two lines of code, when I declare `fx2`, I'm passing `obj` as the first argument (this will ensure the context, used as the `object` variable on the `bind` implementation), then I pass the values `1`,`2` and `3`.

Those values are stored in the `args` variable of the outer closure of `bind`, then as you see in the `bind` implementation, another function is returned.

That function returned in my example is `fx2` after the assignment, in the last line you see I call that function, passing two additionally arguments.

Finally the returned function will call `obj.fx` with the two argument lists, the arguments we pre-filled when calling `bind` (`1`,`2`,`3`) and the arguments when the function actually executed (`4`,`5`).

That is why makes sense concatenating the two argument objects.

Answer (score 1):

> the anonymous function haven't any arguments

The anonymous function *can* actually have arguments (as can the `bind` method itself, which also doesn't declare any arguments).

Type-checking in JavaScript is non-existent: you can pass fewer arguments into a function than are declared in the `function(...)` signature (in which case the arguments that aren't passed get received as `undefined`), and you can pass more than declared, in which case the only way to read them is through the `arguments` array, which always contains exactly how many arguments were passed in, regardless of what's in the function signature.

It's generally considered polite to put a comment in the signature (`function(x, /* y, ... */)`) to indicate that more arguments will be read using the `arguments` array.